# Vb.net Webbrowser Dock at bottom with Textbox Dock at top

Tags: vb.net

In the window, I add a textbox and a Webbrowser Control.

How do I achieved the following picture?

[image]

On runtime when I increase the window size, it becomes like this. How to let the webbrowser dock the entire window without occupying the textbox.
[image]

Comment: Try docking the web browser with `Fill` then right-click it and press `Send to back`.

Comment: I'm in no position to test it and I'm not certain it works, but if you find it does I will post it as an answer.

Comment: i solved it by adding a panel for the textbox then dock it at top then dock inside it the textbox. Then dock the webbrowser at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: You should write that as the answer then. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a panel for the textbox then dock it at top then dock inside it the textbox. Then dock the webbrowser at the bottom. Thanks.